# I am trying to upload a photo to Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am getting an error of `TypeError: _Firebase_index__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.ref is not a function`
Below is the corresponding code to the error.

```
  handleUpload = () => {
const { image } = this.state;
const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
uploadTask.on(
  "state_changed",
  snapshot => {
    // progress function ...
    const progress = Math.round(
      (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
    );
    this.setState({ progress });
  },
  error => {
    // Error function ...
    console.log(error);
  },
  () => {
    // complete function ...
    storage
      .ref("images")
      .child(image.name)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(url => {
        this.setState({ url });
      });
  }
);
```

I have tried to create a `console.log` an error but nothing comes up.

Comment: How is `storage` defined?

Comment: It's in my Firebase folder, in index.js and its not exported.                                       `import FirebaseContext, { withFirebase } from './context';
import Firebase from './firebase';
import Storage from './storage';

export default Firebase;

export { FirebaseContext, withFirebase, Storage };`

Comment: I still don't see the `storage` variable defined in there.

Comment: Note that `Storage` (with an uppercase `S`) and `storage` (with a lowercase `s`) are different variables.